# Firefox script error

Tags: linux, firefox, centos-6

I downloaded Firefox (firefox-15.0.1.tar.bz2) file from this [link](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)

Now That file is present under `/opt` directory, this is the permission of that file

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19280364 Sep 17 15:33 firefox-15.0.1.tar.bz2

I extracted that file using this command

> tar -jvxf firefox-15.0.1.tar.bz2

now the extracted file present in Firefox directory (under /opt)

Inside Firefox directory one script is there `run-mozilla.sh`, this is permission of that script

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     8915 Sep  6 04:52 run-mozilla.sh

I tried this command to execute that script

`sh run-mozilla.sh` but it's showing this error

```
[root@localhost firefox]# sh run-mozilla.sh 

run-mozilla.sh: Cannot execute .
```

I thought that it's a installation script...

Now what should I do, why its showing that error?

I am using CentOS 6.2

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the Firefox package shipped by you distro? `sudo yum update; sudo yum install firefox` should give you Firefox 10.0.5, installed and ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to start Firefox is

```
/opt/firefox/firefox
```

The `run-mozilla.sh` is only used internally. There is no installer.

Comment: Then how to open with GUI. using launcher I can do, but in Applications>Internet it's not showing the `Firefox` option for that what should I do?

Comment: You can create a launcher in the menu yourself, but honestly, that's what package management is for. `yum install firefox` does all that in a user-friendly way.